# Node.js node-csv module - working with a local CSV file

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing

I'm trying to use the new version of the node-csv node module to do some CSV manipulation. 
[node-csv](https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv)

I've used perl in the past, but would like to try JavaScript this time. I'm having trouble figuring out how to import a local CSV file instead of using the built in generator. The documentation for node-csv doesn't show how to do this as far as I can tell(although it does provide an example for the previous version).

Here is the example code, which works as expected.

```
var csv = require('csv');

var generator = csv.generate({seed: 1, columns: 2, length: 20});

var parser = csv.parse();
var transformer = csv.transform(function(data){
  return data.map(function(value){return value.toUpperCase()});
});
var stringifier = csv.stringify();

generator.on('readable', function(){
  while(data = generator.read()){
    parser.write(data);
  }
});

parser.on('readable', function(){
  while(data = parser.read()){
    transformer.write(data);
  }
});

transformer.on('readable', function(){
  while(data = transformer.read()){
    stringifier.write(data);
  }
});

stringifier.on('readable', function(){
  while(data = stringifier.read()){
    process.stdout.write(data);
  }
});
```

I plan on using the FS module, but am not sure how to pass the local file into the node-csv functions.

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

Here is an example for the PREVIOUS version, which uses completely different syntax:

```
// node samples/sample.js
var csv = require('csv');
var fs = require('fs');
csv()
.from.stream(fs.createReadStream(__dirname+'/sample.in'))
.to.path(__dirname+'/sample.out')
.transform( function(row){
  row.unshift(row.pop());
  return row;
})
.on('record', function(row,index){
  console.log('#'+index+' '+JSON.stringify(row));
})
.on('end', function(count){
  console.log('Number of lines: '+count);
})
.on('error', function(error){
  console.log(error.message);
});
```

Any suggestions?